# Why does this method always return false?

Tags: java

I would like to evaluate a phone number using the provided method. The phone number should always have a length of 10. However the following method always seems to return false. Why is that? Thanks.

```
public static boolean valPhoneNumber(String phonenumber){
    boolean result= true; 

    if (phonenumber.length() > 10 || phonenumber.length() < 10){ 
        result= false;            

    }else                           
            phonenumber.length();
            char a=phonenumber.charAt(0); 
            char b=phonenumber.charAt(1);            
            char d=phonenumber.charAt(3);
            char e=phonenumber.charAt(4);
            char f=phonenumber.charAt(5);

            if (a<2 || a>9){ 
               result = false;
            }else if( b<0 || b>8){ 
                result = false;
            }else if (d<2 || d>9){ 
                result = false;
            }else if (e==1 && f==1){ 
                result = false;
            }                  
    return result;
}
```

Comment: `if (phonenumber.length()>10 || phonenumber.length()<10){ ` ^ so only false if the length is 10?

Comment: No, it's true when it's equal 10.

Comment: the code really makes little sense. Can you add a description of what it is supposed to do?

Comment: Then shouldn't the condition be phonenumber.length() != 10?

Comment: The `else` section is missing opening and closing brackets. This won't do what you think it should do.

Comment: It has to be true until one of the situations in if-else happens. so if for example, a is less than 2 the result must change to false. and so on

Comment: `phonenumber.length();` is also a useless statement: it evaluates the length of the string, and then discards the result.

Comment: But if non of the if_else apply, it has to return true.

Comment: Also `a<2` is comparing its ascii value.  I think that all enterable char values will be greater than ascii 9 `a>9`

Comment: you are right. I fixed it. and I also added brackets to else too.

Comment: Thanks Scary Wombat, Ooh, you are right. So do you know how should I check the value of a to be between 2 and 9?

Comment: just a hint: (almost) always use brackets in `if` **and** `else` blocks - `if (condition) { doSomething(); ... } else { somethingElse(); ... }` - the first `else` in your example is very confusing since using no brackets amd still the whole rest of code is (wrongly) indented (not an error but leads to mistakes!)

Answer (score 8):

So looking into your ladder which is comparing character to number. In this case the comparison will happen with ASCII value.

You can put single quotes to check the range:

```
if (a < '2' || a > '9') { 
    result = false;
} else if( b < '0' || b > '8') { 
    result = false;
} else if (d < '2' || d > '9') { 
    result = false;
} else if (e == '1' && f == '1') { 
    result = false;
}
```

One liner:

```
result = !((a < '2' || a > '9') || (b < '0' || b > '8') || (d < '2' || d > '9') || (e == '1' && f == '1'));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your code wrong at the parsing phonenumber.charAt(). This always return char, and when you do comparision with integer it will convert to number which present to that char code (ASCII code). I think you should modify your code to `int a=Character.getNumericValue(phonenumber.charAt(0));` and so on

Answer (score 1):

I think an approach with regex here would be the cleanest and easiest solution.

```
public static boolean valPhoneNumber(String phonenumber){
    String regex = "[2-9][0-8][0-9][2-9][02-9][0-29][0-9]{4}";
    return phonenumber.matches(regex);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should cast the char variables to integer.

Comment: not needed, done by compiler ([15.20.1. Numerical Comparison Operators < , <= , > , and >=](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.20.1): "*Binary numeric promotion is performed on the operands ([§5.6.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2)).*"

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

> int a = Integer.parseInt(phonenumber.substring(0,1));

Comment: more appropriate `Character.digit(phonenumber.charAt(0), 10)`, or even `phonenumber.charAt(0) - '0'`, but, since `char` is already an integral type, it can be compared directly `if (phonenumber.charAt(0) < '2')`

Answer (score 0):

I added single quotes to check the range. Thank you all.

```
public static boolean valPhoneNumber(String phonenumber) {
    boolean result= true; 

    if (phonenumber.length() != 10) { 
        result = false;            
    } else { 
        //phonenumber.length();
        char a = phonenumber.charAt(0); 
        char b = phonenumber.charAt(1);            
        char d = phonenumber.charAt(3);
        char e = phonenumber.charAt(4);
        char f = phonenumber.charAt(5);

        if (a < '2' || a > '9') { 

        } else if( b<'0' || b>'8') {  
            result = false;
        } else if (d < '2' || d > '9') { 
            result = false;
        } else if (e == '1' && f == '1') { 
            result = false;
        }                  
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: How is that different than Bilal Siddiqui's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58445684/85421)? (you already commented it there) - just accept the answer (see [Tour])

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger correct, he is a newbie. @ Farzan you should learn things.